# laravel backpack crud display relationship in list view filter by and update

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How can you display relationships fields and filter by in the list and update views?

lets say I have a transactions table

```
Id, customer_id,  product_id, purchase_date, payment_status
```

a customer table

```
Id, first_name, last_name, email, password
```

a products table

```
Id, product_name, product_description, product_price, stock
```

for example. And I wanted to show in my transactions view:

```
ID, customer.first_name customer.last_name, product.product_name, purchase_date, payment_status
```

and wanted to filter the results by customer name and product name, I have read through the docs and cannot see how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you created Eloquent models that represent each of those tables? Or do you want to know how to fetch the data using the query builder without using Eloquent?

Comment: I have my models and relationships I just don't know how to set the params in the various CrudControllers, TransactionCrudController for example.

Comment: Can you post how your relationships are defined?

Comment: They are belongsTo and hasMany on the reverse they work fine on the front end its just the backpack admin I simply don't know how to display the related fields. On the Transaction model it is simply ''''return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');'''' and ''''return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');'''' and on the customer for example ''''return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction');'''' of course wrapped in named public function.

Comment: And how do you precisly want to filter?.given a transaction you want to see customer and product data? or vice versa?

Comment: I want to see all transactions for selected product or customer

Comment: maybe i am not explaining it very well I want to show the records from a relationship in the view do instead of customer_id I want a column called customer which shows first_name and last_name and instead of product_id I want product_name to be pulled from the respective relationships

Comment: @futureweb ok, got it..i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CrudController in the setup() method :

```
$this->crud->setListView('your-custom-view');
```

If you want, you can use the default list view as a starter and modify it

you can find the default file in vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/list.blade.php.

Don't modify it there because it will show on all Crud views..just take it as a template and save 'your-custom-view' in views.

Maybe this will be of help : https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.3/docs/filters

**Edit:**

Instead of customer_id you want the customer first_name and so on right? This will do the trick:

In your TransactionCrudController:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
        // 1-n relationship
        'label' => "customer", // Table column heading
        'type' => "select",
        'name' => 'customer_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
        'entity' => 'customer', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => "first_name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App/Models/Customer", // foreign key model
    ]);
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not let me know.